# Connection timeout on new website

Tags: iis, timeout

I just rebuilt my server and did a fresh install of Windows Server 2016 and Exchange Server 2016. I created a website for personal stuff and gave it port 8080 (OWA is using 80/443). I added port forwarding on my router for 8080 → 8080. When I hit the site from the server itself (http://localhost:8080), it comes up fine. When I hit it externally, I get "connection timed out." http://canyouseeme.org returns:

```
Error: I could not see your service on [myIPAddress] on port (8080).
```

What are some basic things I can check to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `I just upgraded my server to Windows Server 2016. It's a fresh build/install.` - Those two sentences contradict each other. It's either an upgrade or a new install, but not both.

Comment: @joeqwerty Actually, the word "upgraded" can be taken different ways. Replacing 8-year-old hardware and 8-year-old software is *definitely* an upgrade. However, I edited the question so you would understand.

Comment: OK, you're using the word upgraded in the colloquial sense. I took it literally.  I'm following now. Have you added a Windows Firewall rule for port 8080 inbound allowing the traffic?

Comment: @joeqwerty Ha! You're a genius! (or I'm just clueless, or both). Anyhoo, add that as an answer and I'll give you the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a Windows Firewall rule for port 8080 inbound allowing the traffic? If not, you'll need to.