# Connection timeout on port 8081 (but works on 8080!)

Tags: iis, timeout

I have a new web server (Windows Server 2016/Exchange Server 2016). I got one simple website working on it. See this post:

[Connection timeout on new website](https://serverfault.com/questions/898487/connection-timeout-on-new-website)

That site uses port 8080 (OWA is on 80/443, so I needed an alternate port). After opening up port 8080 in Windows Firewall, that first site worked (Thanks, @joeqwerty!).

Then, I added a second very simple website, but on port 8081. Being a quick study, I also added an exception for that port in Windows Firewall. Much to my chagrin, it still doesn't work. As with the first site, I added port forwarding for port 8081. I also tested it using http://canyouseeme.org and the port works. I can view the site internally (http://localhost:8081).

`netstat -ano` gives this for those ports:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           moe:0                  LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           moe:0                  LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

Again, the site on 8080 works, but not the one on 8081 (timeout error). Any ideas?

EDIT: This is from the HTTPERR log:

```
2018-02-26 18:48:59 fe80::d8cd:799d:e902:e088%5 16360 fe80::d8cd:799d:e902:e088%5 444 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?moe.home.birdus.com:6001 - 400 3 BadRequest MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
2018-02-26 18:50:05 fe80::d8cd:799d:e902:e088%5 16360 fe80::d8cd:799d:e902:e088%5 444 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?moe.home.birdus.com:6001 - 400 3 Connection_Dropped MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
```

EDIT: I tried this, but it didn't fix the problem:

https://dirteam.com/sergio/2014/01/21/bad-request-http-400-error-in-exchange-2013-owaecp/

EDIT: Then, I recreated both sites and pointed them at DefaultAppPool instead of their default self-named newly-created app pools, but that didn't make a difference, either. Just trying anything that comes to mind. 8080 still works, 8081 still doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduce the issue by accessing the application at port 8081 from outside.

Open IIS logs and check if you see an incoming request. Default Location: C:\inetpub\log\logfiles\w3svc_websiteID

If you do see your request coming in, look for the status code at the end of the line. It'll tell you exactly what's going on with the application. But since you said that the application works fine when you locally access it on the server, I doubt if it has anything to do with the application.

However, if you do not see the request in IIS logs, check HTTPERR logs and see if you have any entry there. If you do not have any entry here as well, then I guess the request isn't reaching the server.

Comment: Added info from the error log. I'll research it, but any help here is welcome.

Comment: What kind of applications is the new application running on port 8081 ? Is it ASP.NET, WCF, Exchange ?

Comment: A website. Just an `index.html` which points to some photos in an `/images` folder. Couldn't get much simpler.

Comment: Then I don't think the HTTPERR logs that you have mentioned in your problem statement are relevant because the request executing there was "/rpc/rpcproxy.dll" and not "index.html". 

If you don't see a request for index.html in HTTPERR then it if safe to assume that the request did not make it to IIS.